# "Redirect to Page" action doesn't follow up multilingual in Sitecore Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

My website has been built in multi languages. I am building forms using `Sitecore Form` as well. However, I'm facing an issue with `Redirect to Page` action under submit actions.

I noticed that when I'm in Chinese language, submit form then it redirects to a `Thank you` page but this page is in English version instead of Chinese.

May anyone help to advise on this? I'm using Sitecore 9.0 update 1.

[image]

Comment: Does your `Thank you` page have a version in Chinese language? Do you maybe have `Item Fallback` configured for the `Thank you` page? Is Language Embedding always required for the site where you put the form?

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich Yes, I have `Thank you` page in Chinese language. It requires language embedding as well. I'm using SXA version 1.6 and use Virtual Folder "/zh" for Chinese (e.g zh-HK).

Answer (score 5):

We encountered this same issue - the reason was that when Sitecore creates the AJAX URL for submitting the form data, it does not include a language parameter. So when the form submission is being processed, the context language of the request is not necessarily the language of the page being viewed.

We fixed this by altering the `form.renderForm` pipeline to override the `InitializeAjaxOptions` step to add this parameter. As it's a standard context parameter, it gets picked up by the request and changes the context accordingly.

```
public class LanguageAwareInitializeAjaxOptions : InitializeAjaxOptions
{   
    private const string languageKey = "sc_lang";

    public LanguageAwareInitializeAjaxOptions(IFormRenderingContext formRenderingContext) 
        : base(formRenderingContext)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(RenderFormEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!args.IsPost && !args.QueryString.ContainsKey(languageKey))
        {
            args.QueryString.Add(languageKey, Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
        }

        base.Process(args);
    }
}
```

You then just need to patch this replacement pipeline in:

```
<forms.renderForm>
    <processor patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.InitializeAjaxOptions, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc']"
               type="Your.Solution.Pipelines.RenderForm.LanguageAwareInitializeAjaxOptions, Your.Solution" resolve="true"/>
  </forms.renderForm>
```